# Beetle Mesh Deformation in Pose Mode

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

In Pose mode, when I try to move a armature, even though I weight painted the rest of the mesh to ensure nothing else would get dragged along also, the beetle deforms on it's side, destroying the mesh when I try to move it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happens because many vertices in your mesh are not assigned to any bone so they don't deform.

These steps will solve your problem:

- select your mesh
- while selecting the mesh hit <kbd>shift</kbd> + RightClick to select the armature as well
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then choose automatic weighting

This will solve the problem as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Tak, thank you so much for your response!  Honestly this little bug has been driving me crazy.  Whenever I follow your instruction, I notice that going back into pose mode, either the head or the entire body itself deforms when trying to just move a leg.  Automatic weighting seems to ignore all the focused weight painting I did, so I'm not sure what else is going on here.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Nahum this is because those vertices of the body are assigned to the closest bones, you can adjust this manually. Please don't forget to accept and upvote the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Tak, thank you again for your reply.  I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to this stuff, I'm teaching myself purely off of youtube.  When you say I can adjust the vertices manually, can you please elaborate?